# ESXi 6.0 macOS virtual machine not starting up properly

Tags: macos, vmware, devops, esxi

Hello Stack community,

I have created a Virtual machine with macOS 10.10, but when I go to the main page for the virtual machine, I get a notification saying I need to install VMware Tools.  When I select to install VMWare Tools, I can't see it mounting to the Disk Drive and the machine will persist in saying they are not installed.  Is there a step that I am missing in this installation process?

Answer (score -1):

**user2948723**!
It is about a month from your question and of course, you've been figured it out already.
It's not clear which VM product you used for your experiments, but as I understand, you need to start VM first. When it get loaded - it's time for VM Tools. Look for "Install VMware Tools" in the VM menu. It will mount an iso inside of Guest OS and you can start the installer.
It happens when VM product doesn't have VM Tools preinstalled (`darwin.iso` for macOS for example in some cases). So you can download Tools from "vSphere downloads" page and mount `VMware Tools.iso` and start installer manually. For a example, you can find this `iso` here: https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?downloadGroup=VMTOOLS10115&productId=614.
But you have to register to get files from there.

Good luck!